# Como passar parâmetro de uma formulário para uma rota Laravel em uma API?

Tags: php, laravel, api

> ErrorException in UrlGenerationException.php line 17:
>   Missing required parameters for [Route: v1.clientes.search] [URI: v1/clientes/search/{nome}/{situacao}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\api-atualizador\resources\views\cliente\search.blade.php)

---

```
form role="form" 
     class="horizontal"
     action="{{action('ClientesController@searchBy',$nome ="nome",$situacao ="situacao")}}" 
     method="get"
>
```

---

```
Route::get('/search/{nome}/{situacao}', 
           ['as'=>'v1.clientes.search',
            'uses'=>'ClientesController@searchBy']
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a própria [documentação do Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#urls) Para gerar uma url pasando parâmetros usando o helper `action()`, você deve passar no segundo argumento do helper um *array* com os parâmetros que deseja enviar, ficando assim

```
<form role="form" class="horizontal" method="get" action="{{ action('ClientesController@searchBy',["nome" => $nome, "situacao" => $situacao]) }}" >
```